# ERROR WHILE COMPILING WITH ANDROID NDK

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, box2d, cocos2d-x

I have this error, while compiling with android NDK,

**ERROR LOG**

```
error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<BoundingBox>::iterator, std::vector<BoundingBox>::iterator, CPlayerScoreLabelEntityManager::PostEnterLevelNewEntitySpawned(EntityInfo*, CGameEntity*)::BoundingBoxCompare)'
jni/../../Classes/grannygamelib/CEntityManager.cpp:2695:65: note: candidates are:
/Users/developer2/Documents/PROGRAMMI/ANDROID_NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_algo.h:5431:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)
/Users/developer2/Documents/PROGRAMMI/ANDROID_NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_algo.h:5467:5: note: template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)
```

What can i do ?

Comment: is your NDK ROOT is properly defined  ??  have you tested demo run on eclipse first ??

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, you are trying to use parameters on `sort` function that are not matching the available function signature.

You should call the `sort` function with the correct parameters!

Comment: The same code is compiled with xcode and cocos , and work well.
struct BoundingBoxCompare
 {
  bool operator ()(const BoundingBox &b1, const BoundingBox &b2) const
  {

   if ( b1.x0 < b2.x0 )
    return true;
   if ( b1.x0 > b2.x0 )
    return false;  
   if ( b1.y0 < b2.y0 )
    return true;
   return false;
  }
 };

 sort( b_boxes.begin(), b_boxes.end(), BoundingBoxCompare() );